# No type or storage class may be specified here before 'interface'/'interface' iOS Error (Corrupted Xcode?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

This interface is giving the errors:

```
@interface VideoFeedCollector : NSObject{
    @public
    NSData * received_data;
    int feed_id;
    BOOL transmitting;
}
```

THank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No @end with one of the interface declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Either a circular #import or a syntax error in the `.m` file that imports this header or a syntax error in one of the headers.

Comment: Thank you but there are no more errors shown other than stupid nonsensical ones. I tried making a new project copying references to the files and it still fails so it must be the files...

Comment: I found the interface that has caused it.

Comment: Why on earth doesn't it give errors about no "@end". I figured it out. Phew.

Comment: File a bug about that, please.   (It is syntactically valid to *not* have an `@end` in same file because you might #import it somehow. Stupid, I know, but possible.)